# Using 'netsh interface ip set address' to override another adapter's address?

Tags: windows, ip, ipv4, netsh

I'm one of the developers of the [OpenConnect](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect) VPN client.

We're trying to modernize and improve our support for Windows. We use a user-customizable JScript  called [`vpnc-script-win.js`](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/blob/master/vpnc-script-win.js) to configure IPv4/6 addresses, routing, and DNS based on the configuration sent by the VPN server.

One of the things this script needs to do is to [set specific IP addresses for the VPN network interface](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/blob/master/vpnc-script-win.js#L93-100). We use the command `netsh interface ip set address` to do this for IPv4, like so:

```js
        run("netsh interface ip set address \"" + env("TUNIDX") + "\" static " +
            env("INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS") + " " + env("INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK") + " store=active");
```

One of the limitations of the command is that it *fails* if the IP address in question is “in use” by another adapter (*even if* that adapter is not presently up-and-running):

[image: screenshot]

What I'd like to know is if there is any way to override this behavior, and *force* the setting of an IP address that conflicts with the address set on another adapter. I haven't been able to find anything in Microsoft documentation that explains a way to do this programmatically.

However, from configuring network interfaces on Windows using the Control Panel *GUI*, I know that it is in fact *possible* to configure conflicting IP addresses on Windows, after clicking through a brief warning.

So: is there a way to set an IP address for an adapter on Windows *even if* another adapter is (allegedly) using that address? Ideally, this will be done using command-line tools, since we prefer to keep all of the IP/routing/DNS configuration in this user-customizable script rather than in our binary code.